# Delphi10.1 Berlin.. I get an error when I close the form with the dblookupcombobox menu open

Tags: delphi

I get an error when I close the form having a dblookupcombobox menu opened.

Error message :  `Cannot focus a disabled or invisible window`

If the dblookupcombobox menu is not open, I do not get any error when I close the form, I get an error when I close the form when the menu still open.

```
procedure TForm6.RzButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    with DataModule1.FDQuery6 do begin
        try
            SQL.Clear;
            SQL.Text:='insert into my_table (kayit_adi, fiyat, tarih, aciklama, list_id) values (:kayit_adi, :fiyat, :tarih, :aciklama, :list_id)';
            ParamByName('kayit_adi').Value :=DBLookupComboBox1.Text;
            ParamByName('fiyat').Value:=edit2.Text;
            ParamByName('tarih').AsDate:=RzDateTimePicker1.Date;
            ParamByName('tarih').AsDate:=RzDateTimePicker1.Date;
            ParamByName('aciklama').Value :=Edit3.Text;
            ParamByName('list_id').Value :=DBLookupComboBox1.KeyValue;
            ExecSQL;
        finally
            open ('Select * from my_table where convert(date,tarih) = convert(date, getdate());');
        end;
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please edit your question so that it is more clear. Do not add an image but specify the error message. Show the relevant code. Doing this, you'll get more chance to have a good answer. It is also better if you include a minimal example of code reproducing the error you have. And by the way, the error you have mean exactly what it says!!

Comment: Thank you for your warning I made an arrangement.:)

Comment: I edited a little bit more. Check if what I have done is correct. The code you show is not really what cause the issue. Just an idea: in the form's OnCloseQuery, check if the operation with DbLookupCombobox is done and only accept close when it is done.

Comment: Thanks for everything. my problem was solved in a very short time.  "procedure TForm6.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
DBLookupComboBox1.CloseUp(true);
end;"

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the OnCloseQuery event to close the DBLookupCombobox:

```
TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean); 
begin 
    DBLookupComboBox1.CloseUp(TRUE); 
end;
```